# How can I draw two separate rectangle outlines in OpenGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

In my first project, i just had to draw a single rectangle outline. I did that by using `GLES20.GL_LINE_LOOP` and this indices array in my draw call.

```
private final short[] mIndices = new short[] {
        0,1,2, //triangle 1
        2,3,0 // triangle 2
};
```

Now, I would like to draw a second rectangle outline above the first one. I calculated the vertices and setup the indices like this:

```
private final short[] mIndices = new short[] {
        0,1,2, //triangle 1
        2,3,0, // triangle 2

        // Upper rectangle
        4,5,6, //triangle 3
        6,7,4, // triangle 4
};
```

I am still using `GLES20.GL_LINE_LOOP`. The problem is that the result that is drawn is not exactly what I want. There is one line that connects back to the origin. I **don't** want that line.

What can I do? I guess that line is drawn because of the line loop but I don't know which primitive I could use instead.

This is what my object that is drawn looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with GLES20; you should use LINES and specify which ones you want to draw:

```
private final short[] mIndices = new short[] {
        0,1,1,2, //triangle 1
        2,3,3,0, // triangle 2

        // Upper rectangle
        4,5,5,6, //triangle 3
        6,7,7,4, // triangle 4
};
```

If you had GLES30 you could use primitive restart to start a new loop between the rectangles.